# Optimal way to end treadmill run?

Tags: running

Running on a treadmill and you've nearly completed your defined goal for the day. Say, 5K @9K/h. You feel the need to go that extra mile - but you're stuck. Which is better for long term physical fitness? Should you:

1. Run for longer - run that last 200-300m until you hit your limit?
2. Run faster - push up the speed for the last 200m of the run, simulating a sprint to the end?
3. Turn up the incline for the last 200m - keeps your stats neat and tidy, while still putting in that extra bit of effort?
4. Take it easy, and make a self promise to increase the speed/distance/incline of the next run, or moving the next run forwards a day?
5. Take it easy - you've managed to achieve your objective. Enjoy the fact you've still got some breath left!

Not that I've spent the last ~35 minutes obsessing over this while running at 9k, you understand. Help?

Comment: What do you mean "you're stuck"? How do you get stuck on a treadmill?

Comment: Stuck as in, obsessed about how to end the run for the entire duration of the run.

Comment: Those who marked this question as opinion based:  I assumed that this would have a defined answer - is this purely an opinion matter, without actual science or study?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All exercise progression can benefit from the principle of [progressive overload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_overload).

You should (in the first year or so) try to push yourself to the same extent. Working until failure can be useful for building endurance but doing this every time you train can affect your recovery.

If you push yourself to the same level of physical strain each workout then your ability to do that activity will improve, whether it be you running for longer or faster. With that in mind your workout goals should be adjusted to constantly challenge you. This is the principle of progressive overload.

**Provided you have a good fitness plan then you should trust and stick to it. Don't make it artificially harder.**

Finally, remember you have to do a "cooldown" after a run which should consist of a slow jog/walk and stretching. Working till exhaustion may diminish your ability to do this.

---

note: If you want advice about your specific running progression programme then that is a separate question.